# If statement for time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a little trouble. I am trying to use a Date time format.

I only want to reduce date values that go into the following day. for example: if the start time of column A:A is 2017-10-26 23:00:00 and the end time of column B:B is 2017-10-27 1:00:00 I want to change the values to 2017-10-26 24:59:99.This way when I minus the times I won't include the overflow of time.

This is how far I got

```
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import date

os.chdir('C:\\Python27\\Downloads_prog')

time=pd.read_csv("Agent_Login-Logout_Details_Report_-_Time_Unlimited.csv")

df=pd.DataFrame(time,columns=['Agent Name','Start Timestamp','End Timestamp'])

df['Start Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Timestamp'])
df['End Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['End Timestamp'])

today=date.today()

df['Start Timestamp']=df['Start Timestamp'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(hour=0,minute=0))


today_date= df[(df['Start Timestamp'] >= today)]
```

Comment: `24:59:99`? 24th hour and 99 seconds?

Comment: That'll roll over to `01:00:39`

Comment: Yes I do not want to include any time that roll into the following day just the same day as the start times in columns (all column  dates times need to be same day)